# By general reasons, $i_A \colon \mathbb{D}\text{-}\mathrm{cont}[A,\mathbf{Set}] \to [A,\mathbf{Set}]$ has a left adjoint

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, enriched-category-theory

In Centazzo and Vitale's *A Duality Relative to a Limit Doctrine* (TAC, 2002, [abstract](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/10/20/10-20abs.html)), early on, they make the above claim and cite Kelly's *Basic Concepts in Enriched Category Theory* ([TAC reprints](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html)). I am having difficulty finding exactly where these general reasons are.

Two questions:

(1) What exactly in *Basic Concepts...* are they referring to?

(2) What is an explicit formula for this specific left adjoint?

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not meet any of the questions, yet it provides the reason for which $i_A$ has a left adjoint. The whole story is contained in **Categories of continuous functors I** by *Kelly* and *Freyd*. Nowadays maybe we have more sophisticated ways of phrasing this result, but the core of the reason is still in the paper by Freyd and Kelly, which offers also a historical tour of all the partial results that led to the theorem.

Coming to your *second question*, it is very hard in general to provide an explicit formula. Since the left adjoint $L_A$ has to coincide by abstract nonsense with $\mathsf{ran}_{i_A}(1),$ there exists a somewhat obscure integral expression coming from (co)end calculus.

Comment: Freyd–Kelly: https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(72)90001-1, with erratum https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(74)90033-4

Comment: Thank you @DavidRoberts, you aways provide links for my answers, one day I will learn to embed them every time!

Comment: It is worth to mention that the two perspectives (using FAFT and computing the Kan extension) are equivalent in that FAFT gives a way (the solution set condition) to compute $\text{lim } \big((1\downarrow i_A) \to \mathbb{D}\text{-cont}[A, {\bf Set}]\big)$. Also, Freyd and Kelly's paper gives sufficiently sharp conditions in order to apply AFT, but in concrete examples (eg for very concrete $\mathbb D$), you _might_ find a easier way to find the left adjoint.

Comment: The problem with the usual end formula is that $\mathbb D$-cont(A,Set)$ isn't small, right? Which is why one needs to find solution sets? It's pretty straightforward to show that it is complete.

Comment: I guess it really depends on what you consider an explicit formula, the end formalism is not very explicit to me.